# Android app crashes when trying to animate sprite using cocos2d

Tags: android, animation, cocos2d-iphone, sprite, cocos2d-android

In my android game I'm trying to spawn a projectile that flies across the screen and has an animation using 4 .png files. However whenever a projectile spawns it crashes the entire app. Here's my code:

```
protected void addProjectile() {
    CCSprite projectile = CCSprite.sprite("projectile1.png");
    CCAnimation projectileAnimation = CCAnimation.animation("", 0.1f);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
  projectileAnimation.addFrame(CCSpriteFrameCache.sharedSpriteFrameCache().spriteFrameByName("projectile" + i + ".png"));
    }
    CCAction projectileAction = CCAnimate.action(1, projectileAnimation, true);
        projectile.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(winSize.width + (projectile.getContentSize().width / 2.0f), winSize.height / 2));
        addChild(projectile);
        projectile.setTag(1);
        _projectiles.add(projectile);

        int minDuration = 3;
        int maxDuration = 6;
        int rangeDuration = maxDuration - minDuration;
        int actualDuration = rand.nextInt(rangeDuration) + minDuration;

        CCMoveTo actionMove = CCMoveTo.action(actualDuration, CGPoint.ccp(-projectile.getContentSize().width / 2.0f + 320, winSize.height / 2));
        CCCallFuncN actionMoveDone = CCCallFuncN.action(this, "spriteMoveFinished");
        CCSequence actions = CCSequence.actions(actionMove, actionMoveDone);
        projectile.runAction(actions);
        projectile.runAction(projectileAction);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: any logs, error messages?

Comment: 05-08 20:15:11.981: D/CCSpriteFrameCache(28021): Frame not found: projectile1.png
05-08 20:15:11.981: D/CCSpriteFrameCache(28021): Frame not found: projectile2.png
05-08 20:15:11.981: D/CCSpriteFrameCache(28021): Frame not found: projectile3.png
05-08 20:15:11.981: D/CCSpriteFrameCache(28021): Frame not found: projectile4.png

And a bunch of other errors:
05-08 20:15:11.981: W/System.err(28021): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-08 20:15:11.981: W/System.err(28021):  at com.frozgames.cube_ninja.GameLayer.update(GameLayer.java:490)
05-08 20:15:11.981: W/System.err(28021):  ... 8 more

Comment: You have to load frames from spritesheets into shared frame cache before you can use them.

Comment: I added: 
    for (int i=1; i<=4; i++) {
      CCSpriteFrameCache.sharedSpriteFrameCache().addSpriteFrames("projectile" + i + ".png");
     }
right after:
CCSprite projectile = CCSprite.sprite("projectile1.png");
and now the projectile won't even spawn. Nothing is happening on the screen, but it's not crashing anymore.

Comment: I don't see `addSpriteFrames` method in [CCSpriteFrameCache.h](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/master/cocos2dx/sprite_nodes/CCSpriteFrameCache.h) You have to use one of CCSpriteFrameCache methods to load sprites _from spritesheet_. Spritesheet is an image with many sprites within, and comes with a file that specifies where each sprite is. There are many spritesheet tutorials out in the web, don't be afraid to use your preferred web search engine to find them.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried doing it without a spritesheet cause I didn't know how to make one, but I found texture packer and made one with it and now it works fine.

Comment: can you update the images name which is in Assets , cz Logcat shows that which name you are trying it does not available in the folder